# Не работает JSON в билде

Tags: c#, json, unity3d

У меня есть уровень. Данные хранятся в JSON файле.
Но если я делаю билд то ничего не происходит.

Если что я делаю игру под андроид.
Путь сделан правильно.

Код путя:

```
#if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR
        path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "test.json");
    #else
        path = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "test.json");
    #endif
```

Comment: `Код путя`... А-ха-ха,  Я должен это заскринить

Comment: А чего `ничего` не происходит? Вы же просто скинули код присваивания значения в переменную. Что должно происходить? Чего вы ожидаете?

Comment: У меня в JSON файле есть данные. При запуске сцены другой скрипт их читает и использует. В редакторе всё работает нормально но в билде ничего не происходит.

Comment: Ну там разница не только в пути. На девайсах если не ошибаюсь данные запрашиваются асинхронно, через WWW.